# Update NSDictonary in plist-File

Tags: ios, plist, nsdictionary

I have the following structure in my plist file:

```
<array>
 <dict>
  <key>XX</key>
  <string>value XX</key>
  <key>YY</key>
  <string>value YY</string>
  <key>ZZ</key>
  <string>value ZZ</string>
 </dict>
 <dict>
  ...
 </dict>
</array>
```

Now I want to access the data of the dict with key XX = ID to read and update value YY of that data. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: If the question is just: `Does anyone know how I can do this?` then the answer is just `Yes`. Your question should show research effort. What have you tried? Your question should be `What is wrong with my solution?`, not `What is the solution?`

Comment: sorry, i currently don't know how to access my plist file items in the right way. Updating later seems to be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSMutableDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableDictionary) Documentation.

For reading the dictionary from file use

```
+ (id)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
```

For adding value

```
- (void)setObject:(id)anObject forKey:(id < NSCopying >)aKey
```

Get value associated with a given key.

```
- (id)objectForKey:(id)aKey
```